# Extract filename and common name from Apache Log with Python

Tags: python, apache, parsing, logging

I am trying to parse an apache log file with the hope of extracting an AD Common name and a Filename from an access.log file via python.

My access.log file is as follows:

```
[01/Jan/1901:12:00:01] 12.34.56.78 TLS Protocol EncryptionMethod "GET/.../filename.zip HTTP/1.1" "CN=Smith John A,......"
```

What I am trying to extract is the following format: `Smith John A, filename.zip`

I have tried to utilize several custom python apache log parsers from Github without any luck.

Any thoughts to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Really basic.

```
import re
with open('access.log') as log:
    for line in log.readlines():
        results = [_.group() for _ in re.finditer(r'"([^"]*)"', line)]
        if len(results) == 2:
            print (results)
        else:
            print (line)
            print ("**** can't parse")
            continue
        m = re.search(r'GET\/.*?([a-z._]+) ', line, re.I)
        count = 0
        if m:
            filename = m.groups(0)[0]
            count += 1
        else:
            filename = ''
        m = re.search(r'CN=([^,]+),', line, re.I)
        if m:
            name = m.groups(0)[0]
            count += 1
        else:
            name = ''
        print (name, filename)
        if count != 2:
            print ("***can't parse filename or name")
```

Untested!

Result for that single-line file:

```
['"GET/.../filename.zip HTTP/1.1"', '"CN=Smith John A,......"']
Smith John A filename.zip
```